# user script Javascript to change element value inside dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, greasemonkey

I need to use a javascript *user script* (through GreasMonkey/TamperMonkey extensions or else) to change the default values of some input text boxes inside some iframe that is created dynamically in a web service.

Using the console window of chrome when the javascript context is at **top** I can access to the required element through something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentDocument.getElementById('txtCode1')
```

So now what can I do to have a generalized Greasemonkey code to access the input texts (that are dynamically created, not on the load of the page) and change the default values to the desired ones?

Comment: [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: The question is too general/broad. Use MutationObserver to detect iframes then use MutationObserver inside the iframe (or just wait via setTimeout) for the inputs to appear.